# How compatible is Traveller5 content with Classic Traveller?

Tags: edition-comparison, traveller

I'd like to use Traveller5 as a toolbox for Classic Traveller - is that possible without (too much) tinkering? For example, can I use the VehicleMaker in order to create CT ships - at least with only a sensible amount of additional effort?

I'm quite aware of the fact that a part of this issue has been covered with [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/411/which-traveller-editions-are-mostly-compatible) question, but I'm looking for more specific answers, since I haven't bought T5 yet but consider doing so.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Specific how? I'm voting to put this on hold as a duplicate until it's clearer how it isn't. Ideally we aim for questions and answers to be thorough and self-contained -- if you would elaborate on what you're looking for and it isn't specific enough to warrant being separate from that question then we can edit those to include this.

Comment: Hello LitheOhm, thanks for the welcome. What I mean is: Can I use all the *Makers of T5 with no or only reasonable modifications in order to use the created weapons etc. for CT? Furthermore, is it connected to a lot of tinkering to use the new life-paths and the corresponding skills for CT? I'm not sure, but I hope I've made myself a little bit clearer...

Answer (score 4):

Define "too much tinkering"?

In general, T5 is a superset of CT, so I'd say there will be additional tinkering (careers, luxuries). Also, T5 was influenced by MgT, because both were developed by same people, and thus teams designing the rules worked together. Examples, see Wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveller_(role-playing_game)#Traveller5_.282013.2C_FFE.29

I'd say: give yourself some time limit and give it a try. If one character takes more than X minutes / hours / whatever your time limit is, drop it, unless you have a good reason for converting; i.e. something ails you in CT rules.

Comment: Other 'way 'round: MgT was influenced by T5 (although, paradoxically, I believe MgT came out first).

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: yes, T5 stuff works with CT.

The longer answer is:

1. T5 Characters work as "advanced" CT characters, or MegaTraveller characters, by dividing skills and knowledges in half.
2. Equipment in the T5 equipment list should just work as-is.
3. Weapons made in T5 work fine with CT, provided you use Burden as an advantageous DM for use.

   - Example: you build a Rifle in T5 with a Burden of -1 and port it to CT.  Find the advantageous Dexterity numbers for Rifles in CT and add that -1 to them, and you've got your Dex ratings for that weapon.
4. Armor made in T5 is not as useful in CT, since there are so few types of armor in CT. However, you can of course use T5 armor as "color" variants of CT armor.
5. Vehicles made in T5 work fine with CT, period.
6. Robots made in T5 work fine with CT, period.  Just treat them as any other NPCs.
7. Starships made in T5 work fine with CT, period.  As with armor, T5 ships may have extra detail (landing skids, floating hulls, sensors), but it could serve just fine as in-game color.

Comment: Thanks for that.  The formatting options are certainly easier to use than BBCode...